# Call to a member function all() on array in laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.4

I am getting this error:

> FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 485:
>
> Call to a member function all() on array

my register controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'fullname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['fullname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }
        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the controller you've posted with your question. What package are you using to allow you to use `mongodb`?

Comment: "jenssegers/mongodb": "^2.3"

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `jenssegers/mongodb`.

Looking at https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb the compatability charts shows that 2.3 doesn't satisfy Laravel 5.3+.

The reason you're getting that specific error is because in Laravel 5.3 a change was made to the query builder so it would return a collection instead of an array, however, 2.3 of `jenssegers/mongodb` just returns an array. In version 3.1 of `jenssegers/mongodb` there is now a check to determine which version of Laravel you're using for this reason.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did this answer your question, @MukeshRawat?